# Python - PyPDF2 re searching string and reporting page numbers of PDF where search term is found

Tags: python, pdf, search

I am looking for a way to find a search term via Python in a PDF (or word document though I understand this is much more difficult to do so) and report the page numbers where this appears in an excel file. I have been researching for the last few weeks and came across the below code (many thanks to the publisher - I have included his URL in the code as a comment!).

There is an issue though - in the original document I use before converting the word document into PDF, there are textboxes on the right hand side of the main narrative body which are the search terms I am trying to pick up. An example of the search term is "AxI. 1.2" however this does not seem to be searchable by the code in Python. The code works for all other words in the main text though. Is someone able to assist or share their thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I have very little coding experience:

The result to the below code outputs to a newly created spreadsheet in the folder where your IDE or python is located and created two columns which have "sheet number" and "search word" located at the top of table - sheet number is the page number upon which the the search word is located on the PDF and the search word is the search term you used within the code.

My goal is to modify the code below somehow to take into account the textboxes in a PDF - the code does not seem to search within these but only in the main body of text of the PDF when converted from a simple word document.

source website: https://craigdanielmiller.com/2016/09/10/finding-words-with-pypdf2/

```
import PyPDF2
import re

pdfFileObj=open(r'FilePath\FileName.pdf',mode='rb')
pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
number_of_pages=pdfReader.numPages

pages_text=[]
words_start_pos={}
words={}

searchwords=['Searchtermhere']

with open('FoundWordsList.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format("Sheet Number", "Search Word"))
    for word in searchwords:
        for page in range(number_of_pages):
            print(page)
            pages_text.append(pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText())
            words_start_pos[page]=[dwg.start() for dwg in re.finditer(word, pages_text[page].lower())]
            words[page]=[pages_text[page][value:value+len(word)] for value in words_start_pos[page]]
        for page in words:
            for i in range(0,len(words[page])):
               if str(words[page][i]) != 'nan':
                    f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(page+1, words[page][i]))
                    print(page, words[page][i])
# source website: https://craigdanielmiller.com/2016/09/10/finding-words-with-pypdf2/
```

Comment: As is, your question is impossible to answer. Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors or exceptions?

Comment: Apologies Robert, I have modified the post and managed to insert the code in my question (first time posting on stack overflow!). I have added in another paragraph of commentary on what happens when it runs and what my goal is. Re errors or exceptions - it simply does not fill in the created output spreadsheet with page numbers and search terms used whereas normally it will be populated with page numbers and search words. Hope that explains a bit better